# error in uploading file larger than 2 mb

Tags: php

I have 2 php files:
1st
name form_upload.php

```
 <html>
    <head><title>File Upload</title></head>
    <body>
    <ol>
        <li>Enter the file name of the product picture you want to upload or the the browse button to navigate to the picture file</li>
        <li>when the path to the picture file shows in the text field, click the upload picture</li>
    </ol>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadFile.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000"/>
    <input type="file" name="pix" size="60"/>
    <p><input type='submit' name="Upload" value="Upload picture"/></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2nd: uploadFile.php

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['Upload']))
{
    include("form_upload.php");
}
else
{
    if($_FILES['pix']['tmp_name']=="none")
    {
        echo "file did not successfully upload. Check the file size. File must be less than 500K";
        include("form_upload.php");
        exit();
    }
    if(!preg_match("/image\/jpeg/",$_FILES['pix']['type']))
    {
        echo "only jpg files are allowed. Please try another file";
        include("form_upload.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $destination='C:\xampp\htdocs\test\hinh\ '.$_FILES['pix']['name'];
        $temp_file=$_FILES['pix']['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($temp_file,$destination);
        echo "<p>the file has successfully uploaded :{$_FILES['pix']['name']} {$_FILES['pix']['type']} ({$_FILES['pix']['size']}) </p>";


    }
}
```

I can not output the first statement. When i upload a picture that larger than 2MB, it always output the second one. Did i do something wrong ?

Comment: `if($_FILES['pix']['tmp_name']=="none")` -- how is that related to the file size?

Comment: most likely a host setting.... default limit is usually 2 meg

Comment: Note that `MAX_FILE_SIZE` setting is... merely a convenience feature for users on the client side of the application. `The PHP settings (on the server side) for maximum-size, however, cannot be fooled.` [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 0):

add

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

in htaccess

or change this values

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

in **php.ini**

and restart web server

10M stands for 10 megabytes, you can insert another value

Comment: assumes of course that host gives access to php.ini or allows htaccess overrides